# Performance of constant references over non-constant references

Tags: c++, performance, compiler-construction, compiler-optimization

Is there a difference in performance when using a constant reference and a non-constant reference in C++? If yes, then which is better and why?

There is a statement in the [SystemC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SystemC) manual that passing objects by non-const reference is a fast solution.

Comment: `const-reference` and `non-const-reference` uses in different cases. When you have guarantee, that in your function object will not be changed - use `const-refenrence`, if you want changes - use `reference`.

Comment: i know the usage, i want to know if one of them is is better than other in terms of performance.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no difference at all. The `const` only applies locally, but any recent compiler is trivially able to determine if a reference has been changed, so it makes no difference.

Consider this scenario:

```
void MyClass::foo(const int& param)
{
    m_myInt1 = param + 1;
    m_myInt2 = param;
}
```

In both these cases, each access to `param` must go through memory. Why? Because `param` may alias `m_myInt1`.

```
MyClass bar;
bar.foo(bar.m_myInt1);
```

The `const` reference only means that `param` cannot be modified through that reference. You can still modify it through some other reference (in this case, through `this->m_myInt1`).

Comment: I'd add a small note: if you pass the const reference to a function it's easier for compiler to inline its body because it won't have to deal with aliasing and object reassigment.

Comment: @UnknownGosu: Even if the reference is `const`, the function could modify it using `const_cast`, so the compiler can't make any extra assumptions based on it being `const`.